# how to view youtube video

Tags: java, android, video

I am finding great difficulties to view YouTube videos in my app.

here is my code:

```
package com.example.webvideo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class WebVideo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        mc.setAnchorView(vv);
        vv.setMediaController(mc);

        vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://youtu.be/2OIOOb-0t44"));
        vv.start();


       }
    }
```

The emulator is showing an error that the video cannot be played.

What am I doing wrong? Am I giving the URL in a wrong format?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that the URI you need to give is to the actual media file to be played.  I wouldn't count on redirects working either...  and anyway that redirect you give seems to point to a YouTube web page, which I sure wouldn't expect the video player to be able to render.

Answer (score 0):

`http://youtu.be/2OIOOb-0t44` is certainly an invalid URL. Maybe you meant `http://youtube.com/watch?v=2OIOOb-0t44`?

Comment: @Thomas Padron-McCarthy: You would appear to be correct. But one wonders how well the VideoView class handles the redirect.

Comment: First of all thanks for your valuable suggestions but I have tried this(http://youtube.com/watch?v=2OIOOb-0t44) kind of URL too but its not working. Again the error is displayed on the emulator that the video cannot be played. Is there any other method for playing video from web or any other URL giving techniques. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are using is for the webpage where you can view it, not for the video itself. The embedding URL appears to be http://www.youtube.com/embed/2OIOOb-0t44, but I think it's HTML5, not flash... you may have to go old school and track down an AVI or MPEG file.

Comment: can you be more specific as I am not getting what you are trying to say. I dont know how to give a URL of a video. Can u do me a favour plz make one app which show video from web using Video View. I will be very thankful to you if you can help me on this.